# Can I download a file from a package without installing it?

Tags: package-management

If I want, for example, `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-96/README.txt.gz` from [nvidia-96](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/i386/nvidia-96/filelist), is there a way for me to download just this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can download the .deb file from packages.ubuntu.com and then open it like an archive (using file-roller). There are two more archives inside, you'll need to open "data.tar.gz".

Comment: I chose this answer because it's simplest/most easily repeatable.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use the graphical file-roller as suggested in another answer, there are some other options:

- Install the debian-goodies package, and run `debmany nvidia-96`; this will present a dialog of documentation files in the package, and you can press Enter to view any one of them.
- (Lower-level:) Download the .deb file using whatever method you prefer, and run `dpkg --fsys-tarfile foo.deb | tar xO ./usr/share/doc/nvidia-96/README.txt.gz` (the leading dot after `tar xO` is required).

Comment: +1 for the complete extraction command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `sudo apt-get -d install nvidia-96` to download package without installation

Comment: he would still need to extract it someway and look for the file. More complete answer requested.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
sudo aptitude download nvidia-96
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -d <"package" or "packages">
```

Here `-d` parameter only downloads packages and not install the packages. You can find the downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt` folder.

If you use Synaptic, then select downloads only option.